# Flex popup issue with keyboard key like C,V,X,A key

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

As i report earlier in the issues of pop-up of that i'm not able to write "a,c, v and x" characters in the text-input field in pop-up.

Shortcut actions(a = select all, c= copy, v = paste and x = cut) are performed on those keys on keys text-input fields.

**Complete case:**

In the popup there is a data-grid and in the data-grid an item renderer where i enter the input.

**Here is code**

```
<CheckBoxGrid:CheckBoxDataGrid id="id_DataGrid"
                               width="95%" height="90%"  allowMultipleSelection="true" editable="true"
                               dataProvider="{inHouseLabList}"
                               draggableColumns="false" 
                               useRollOver="false"
                               styleName="gridStyle"
                               rowCount="{id_DataGrid.dataProvider.length + 1}"
                               variableRowHeight="true" columnWidths="{[20,'10%','25%', '25%','30%']}">
    <CheckBoxGrid:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="" 
                           headerText="" 
                           rendererIsEditor="true"
                           sortable="false" 
                           itemRenderer="com.zigron.controls.extended.components.CheckBoxGrid.CheckBoxRenderer" 
                           headerRenderer="com.zigron.controls.extended.components.CheckBoxGrid.CheckBoxHeaderRenderer" 
                           editorDataField="selected" 
                           />
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Test Code"       dataField="InHouseLabTestTypeDTO.TestCode"  editable="false" sortable="false"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Test Name"       dataField="InHouseLabTestTypeDTO.TestName"  editable="false"  />
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Result"          dataField="TestResult" editable="true"      />
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Normal Range"    dataField="InHouseLabTestTypeDTO.TestRange"     editable="false" />
    </CheckBoxGrid:columns>
</CheckBoxGrid:CheckBoxDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works without issues in FF11, **DataGrid** in a **popup** with a **TextInput** in an **itemRenderer**, *A,C,V,X* or *CTRL+A,C,V,X* works:

**Application.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    minWidth="955" minHeight="600" layout="vertical">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var popup:MyPopup = new MyPopup();
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup, this)
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Button label="click me!" click="clickHandler(event)" />

</mx:Application>
```

**MyPopup.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Panel xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="400" height="300">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable]
            private var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{}]);

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:DataGrid width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{ac}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="MyTextInput">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:TextInput />
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>

</mx:Panel>
```

Please try it and report.

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry, No improvement in functionality.

Comment: You mentioned a bug, I gave you the code without bugs. Whats wrong?